# restrict pointers as function arguments in OpenMP for loops?

Tags: c, openmp

I don't know how OpenMP works, but I presume calling a function with restricted pointer arguments inside a parallel for loop doesn't work if the objects could be shared by multiple threads? Take the following example of serial code meant to perform a weighted sum across matrix columns:

```
const int n = 10; 
const double x[n][n] = {...};  // matrix, containing some numbers
const double w[n] = {...};     // weights, containing some numbers

// my weighted sum function
double mywsum(const double *restrict px, const double *restrict pw, const int n) {
    double tmp = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) tmp += px[i] * pw[i];
    return tmp;
}

double res[n]; // results vector
const double *pw = &w[0]; // creating pointer to w 

// loop doing column-wise weighted sum
for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    res[j] = mywsum(&x[0][j], pw, n);
}
```

Now I want to parallelize this loop using OpenMP, e.g.:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    res[j] = mywsum(&x[0][j], pw, n);
}
```

I believe the `*restrict px` could still be valid as the particular elements pointed to can only be accessed by one thread at a time, but the `*restrict pw` should cause problems as the elements of `w` are accessed concurrently by multiple threads, so the `restrict` clause should be removed here?

Comment: You do not need the `restrict` keyword at all, because you only read from memory.

Comment: Thanks @Laci, my real problem is a bit more complicated than this, so I thought it would be good to tell the compiler that this data is not accessed by any other means. As far as I am informed, aliasing refers to both read and write operation through multiple pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I presume calling a function with restricted pointer arguments inside a parallel for loop doesn't work if the objects could be shared by multiple threads?

**The `restrict` keyword is totally independent of using multiple threads**. It  tells the compiler that the pointer target an object that is **not aliased**, that is, referenced by any other pointers in the function. It is **meant to avoid aliasing** in C. The fact that other threads can call the function is not a problem. In fact, if threads write in the same location, you have a much bigger problem: a *race condition*. If multiple threads read in the same location, this is not a problem (with or without the `restrict` keyword). The compiler basically does not care about multi-threading when the function `mywsum` is compiled. It can ignore the effect of other threads since there is no locks, atomic operations or memory barriers.

> I believe the *restrict px could still be valid as the particular elements pointed to can only be accessed by one thread at a time, but the *restrict pw should cause problems as the elements of w are accessed concurrently by multiple threads, so the restrict clause should be removed here?

It should be removed because it is **not useful**, but not because it cause any issue.

The use of the `restrict` keyword is not very useful here since the compiler can easily see that there is no possible overlapping. Indeed, the only store done in the loop is the one of `tmp` which is a local variable and the input arguments cannot point on `tmp` because it is a local variable. In fact, compilers will store `tmp` in a register if optimizations are enabled (so it does not even have an address in practice).

One should keep in mind that `restrict` is bound to the function scope where it is define (ie. in the function `mywsum`). Thus, inlining or the use of the function in a multithreaded context have no impact on the result with respect to the `restrict` keyword.

---

I think `&x[0][j]` is wrong because the loop of the function iterate over `n` items and the pointer starts to the `j`-th item. This means the loop access to the item x[0][j+n-1] theoretically causing **out-of-bound accesses**. In practice you will observe no error because 2D C array are flatten in memory and `&x[0][n]` should be equal to `&x[1][0]` in your case. The result will certainly not what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jérôme Richard, for the answer. I understand it in so far that the restrict here is a local qualifier that only affects what happens inside the function, and therefore the program is not affected by parallelizing the outer loop. Regarding the general use of restrict, why would it not be useful to tell the compiler that the data is not accessed by any other means inside the function, even if the function has additional pointers as input arguments?

Comment: I did not put much thought into the array loop, but thanks for pointing in out. My real problem uses a different data structure where this kind of loop works.

Comment: It is not useful *in this specific case* since compilers do not need this information to optimize the code very well (theoretically, they can produce an optimal code without this information). This does not mean `restrict` is useless in general though. It would be more useful for example for an array copy (though most mainstream compilers are clever enough so to get ride of the aliasing issue using a pre-check).

Comment: The use of the `restrict` is very dependent of the use-case. If you are sure that there is no aliasing, then use it. The thing is if pointers actually alias, then the compiler will generate a bogus program that is very hard to debug because they can make crazy assumption when your program is ill formed (ie. does not respect the standard). They can remove assertions, making them always pass why a debugger shows the assertion is wrong, and can even optimize out huge piece of code. Aliasing errors are not rare in big applications and are often detected very lately because of sneaky silent bugs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the qualification, I will be more careful in my use of `restrict`.

Comment: Just a side note: `restrict` is often uses in C because it often prevent the code auto-vectorization. OpenMP SIMD directives (`omp simd`) can help to fix this problem while using weaker hypothesis (safer). It is not a silver-bullet in practice though, but it is worth trying.